# How to fix Error "in is.finite: default method not implemented for type 'list'" in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse, shinydashboard

I am getting " **Error in is.finite: default method not implemented for type 'list'** " while generate table in R shiny UI. Lefthand side we have select option to input the parameters to subset the data. Righthandside we have table as outcome with 'Brokerage' %age values for 'Product' and 'Agegroups'.

code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

datax <- read_excel("kaushik.xlsx")

ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Demo"),
    dashboardSidebar(" "),
    dashboardBody( h2("This is kind of demo work", align = 'center'),
      column(width = 4,
      selectInput("gender", "Gender", choices = c("Male", "Female")),
      selectInput("marital", " ", choices = NULL),
      selectInput("state", " ", choices = NULL),
      selectInput("city", " ", choices = NULL),
      selectInput("quali", " ", choices = NULL),
      selectInput("occup", " ", choices = NULL)),
      column(width=8, 
            box(width = 12,
             tableOutput("test1")))
    )))

    library(dplyr)

    datax <- read_excel("kaushik.xlsx")

server <- shinyServer(
  function(session, input,output){

   observe({
        #print(input$gender)
        x = datax %>%  filter(Gender == input$gender) %>% select(Married)
        updateSelectInput(session, "marital", "Married", choices = unique(x))
      })
     observe({
      y = datax %>%  filter(Married == input$marital) %>% select(State)
      updateSelectInput(session, "state", "State", choices = unique(y))
    })

    observe({
      z = datax %>%  filter(State == input$state) %>% select(City)
      updateSelectInput(session, "city", "City", choices = unique(z))
    })

    observe({
      q = datax %>%  filter(City == input$city) %>% select(Qualification)
      updateSelectInput(session, "quali", "Qualification", choices = unique(q))
    })
    observe({
      o = datax %>%  filter(Qualification == input$quali) %>% select(Occupation)
      updateSelectInput(session, "occup", "Occupation", choices = unique(o))
    })


    observe({
      u = datax %>%  filter(Occupation == input$occup) %>% select(Product, Agegroup, 
Brokerage)
      newdata = as.data.frame(u)
      brksum = sum(newdata$Brokerage)
      newdata$percent = (newdata$Brokerage)*100/brksum
      newdata1 <- as.data.frame(newdata)
      newdata2 <- subset(newdata1, select = c(Product, Agegroup,percent))
      output$test1 <- renderTable({
        newdata_1 <-  pivot_wider(newdata2,  names_from = Agegroup, values_from = percent)
      })
  })
  shinyApp(ui,server)
```

The outcome should be as shown in the image [image].
Any help to fix this error would be greatly appreciable.

Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have sample data. How to upload the excel file?

Comment: Use `dput(datax)` and post the output of that in your question.

Comment: Also, `dput(head(datax))` might suffice, if you have more than 6 rows.

Comment: block of code :    observe({
          u = datax %>%  filter(Occupation == input$occup) %>% select(Product, 
     Agegroup, Brokerage)
          newdata = as.data.frame(u)
          brksum = sum(newdata$Brokerage)
          newdata$percent = (newdata$Brokerage)*100/brksum
          newdata1 <- as.data.frame(newdata)
          newdata2 <- subset(newdata1, select = c(Product, Agegroup,percent))
          newdata3 <- dput(newdata2)
          output$test1 <- renderTable({
            newdata_1 <-  pivot_wider(newdata3,  names_from = Agegroup, 
    values_from = percent)
          })

Answer (score 0):

The last block of code in server should be as below:

```
observe({
      u = datax %>%  filter(Occupation == input$occup) %>% select(Product, 
Agegroup, Brokerage)
      newdata = as.data.frame(u)
      output$test1 <- renderTable({
        newdata1 <- newdata %>% select(Product,Agegroup,Brokerage) %>% 
group_by(Product,Agegroup) %>% summarise(sum(Brokerage))
        colnames(newdata1)[3] <- "Brokerage"  
        brksum = sum(newdata1$Brokerage)
        newdata1$percent = (newdata1$Brokerage)*100/brksum
        newdata_1 <-  pivot_wider(newdata1,  names_from = Agegroup, 
 values_from = percent)
        newdata2 <- newdata_1[ , c("Product","20-40","40-60","60+")]
    
    })
```

Comment: If this answer works for you that is fine.  If you are expecting someone to help you, please update your question with this code and post some sample data, and then delete this answer.  Also, avoid nesting reactives.